# Run script from .bash_profile for first Terminal tab/window only

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line

I want to run a script from .bash_profile, but only for the first Terminal window/tab which I open. How can I prevent script execution when opening additional windows/tabs?

Comment: A separate shell binary runs in each of the windows. Wich problem are you trying to solve here?

Comment: @nohillside I want to launch a script from .bash_profile but only from the first terminal shell

Comment: Does the script start another application in the background then, or similar?

Comment: @nohillside yes it does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this script starts an application/binary, the usual way to prevent several executions is to first check whether that binary is already running (`man ps` or `man psgrep` might help) and only launch it if it isn't already started.

As an alternative you could look into LaunchAgents to start the binary directly when you log in (and even have it restarted automatically in case it crashes).

Comment: Right @nohillside I can also use pgrep like here https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/246760

Comment: @Puzzled Indeed, there are several ways to solve this.